# How do you reference classes in an Android library project

Tags: android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to fork my android app, and came upon a method thanks to my [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125723/how-to-fork-my-android-app) using a library project. It is working fine enough for drawables and String assets. But now I've run into a problem.

I have a class (*not* an activity) which extends `Application`. I moved this class into my library project, and want to use it for the main application class in my two derived apps (works fine when directly in the main app).

Say my library is `my.project.library` and my app using the library is `my.project`
In the manifest for `my.project` I specified the following:

`<application android:name="my.project.library.AppClass">`

It compiles and deploys fine, but when I try to run it, it force-closes with the following exception:

`11-15 03:14:25.707: E/AndroidRuntime(16800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application my.project.library.AppClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.project.library.AppClass in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/my.project.apk]`

From the drawables I also imported from the library, it seems that the library contents get in-lined into the main app. So I tried changing my manifest to:

`<application android:name="my.project.AppClass">`

but I still get the same error.

How can i reference a class in the library as my Application class in the main app?

Comment: So you have two modules for the same app or I didn't understand your question :)?

Comment: No, it's more that I have two apps in which I want to use the same class from a library, so as to avoid having duplicated code. The effort is to make a free and paid versions of an app, while as much as possible keeping one codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original reference was correct.

That is:

```
<application android:name="my.project.library.AppClass">
```

Sounds like you not referencing the library project properly see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html the Referencing a Library Project section.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try when I get home. I was looking at that last night in the manifest GUI editor, ... but was confused because I added the library project to the project reference properties under `Project(right-click) > Properties`. Would've kind of expected Eclipse to add the reference fully. But I'll check this tonight.

Comment: I tried this, but now I cannot deploy my app at all. I get the error `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`. I'm confused, because according to my other linked question, I thought that the library was packaged into the main app APK on deployment, so why should I be getting a missing reference error?

Comment: Okay, ... odd. But i think i fixed it. I had set required to true... figuring that, well, the library IS required for my app to work. This caused the `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` though, and when i set required = false, then it no longer throws that error, deploys fine, and runs as expected. Interesting. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not described the library that you are using in the manifest so you need to add something like this to the manifest.

```
<uses-library android:name="my.project.library" />
```

Comment: I tried this, but now I cannot deploy my app at all. I get the error `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`. I'm confused, because according to my other linked question, I thought that the library was packaged into the main app APK on deployment, so why should I be getting a missing reference error?

Comment: have you actually added the library to your project properly? Seems like there is some problem with your project settings .

Comment: Yes, the library was also added in project properties. When I add the using directive, I set the `required` attribute to true because, well, the app requires the library. This caused the error about missing library. I set required=false, and then everything worked splendid. Odd. I guess the required attribute doesn't do what it sounds like. But, it's all good now.